# Extracting breakpoints with intervals closed on the left

Tags: regex, r, cut

I'm looking at the example menu of the command `cut()` (`example(cut)`), specifically this part:

```
cut> aaa <- c(1,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5,6,7)

cut> cut(aaa, 3)
[1] (0.994,3] (0.994,3] (3,5]     (3,5]     (3,5]     (0.994,3]
[7] (3,5]     (3,5]     (3,5]     (5,7.01]  (5,7.01] 
Levels: (0.994,3] (3,5] (5,7.01]

cut> cut(aaa, 3, dig.lab = 4, ordered = TRUE)
[1] (0.994,2.998] (0.994,2.998] (2.998,5.002] (2.998,5.002]
[5] (2.998,5.002] (0.994,2.998] (2.998,5.002] (2.998,5.002]
[9] (2.998,5.002] (5.002,7.006] (5.002,7.006]
Levels: (0.994,2.998] < (2.998,5.002] < (5.002,7.006]

cut> ## one way to extract the breakpoints
cut> labs <- levels(cut(aaa, 3))

cut> cbind(lower = as.numeric( sub("\\((.+),.*", "\\1", labs) ),
cut+       upper = as.numeric( sub("[^,]*,([^]]*)\\]", "\\1", labs) ))
     lower upper
[1,] 0.994  3.00
[2,] 3.000  5.00
[3,] 5.000  7.01
```

Where the intervals are **closed on the right** (as shown above), then it shows me a way to extract the breakpoints of the data using `cbind()`

Now, let's suppose my data will by cut, but indicating that the intervals are **closed on the left**.

```
cut(aaa, 3, dig.lab = 4, ordered = TRUE, right = FALSE)
```

How can I extract now my breakpoints using the same command `cbind()`? (If there are more ways, you're welcome)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use something like the following for your pattern, and use `gsub` instead: `"\\[|\\]|\\(|\\)"`.

An example.

```
out <- levels(cut(aaa, 3, dig.lab = 4, ordered = TRUE, right = FALSE))
gsub("\\[|\\]|\\(|\\)", "", out)
# [1] "0.994,2.998" "2.998,5.002" "5.002,7.006"
```

And, here's a quick way to read that data in:

```
read.csv(text = gsub("\\[|\\]|\\(|\\)", "", out), header = FALSE)
#      V1    V2
# 1 0.994 2.998
# 2 2.998 5.002
# 3 5.002 7.006
```

---

FYI: The same pattern would work whether the intervals are closed on the left or on the right. Using your original example:

```
labs <- levels(cut(aaa, 3))
labs
# [1] "(0.994,3]" "(3,5]"     "(5,7.01]" 
read.csv(text = gsub("\\[|\\]|\\(|\\)", "", labs), header = FALSE)
#      V1   V2
# 1 0.994 3.00
# 2 3.000 5.00
# 3 5.000 7.01
```

---

As for alternatives, since you just need to strip out the first and last character before you can use `read.csv`, you can also easily use `substr` without having to fuss with regular expressions (if that's not your thing):

```
substr(labs, 2, nchar(labs)-1)
# [1] "0.994,3" "3,5"     "5,7.01"
```

---

#### Update: A totally different alternative

Since it is obvious that R has to calculate these values and store them as part of the function in order to generate the output you see, it is not too difficult to manipulate the function to get it to output different things.

Looking at the code for `cut.default`, you'll find the following as the last few lines:

```
if (codes.only) 
    code
else factor(code, seq_along(labels), labels, ordered = ordered_result)
```

It's really easy to change the last few lines to output a `list` that contains the output of `cut` as the first item, and the calculated ranges (from the `cut` function directly, not extracting from the pasted together `factor` `labels`.

For instance, [**in the Gist I've posted at this link**](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/7251969), I've changed those lines as follows:

```
if (codes.only) 
  FIN <- code
else FIN <- factor(code, seq_along(labels), labels, ordered = ordered_result)
list(output = FIN, ranges = data.frame(lower = ch.br[-nb], upper = ch.br[-1L]))
```

Now, compare:

```
cut(aaa, 3)
#  [1] (0.994,3] (0.994,3] (3,5]     (3,5]     (3,5]     (0.994,3] (3,5]     (3,5]    
#  [9] (3,5]     (5,7.01]  (5,7.01] 
# Levels: (0.994,3] (3,5] (5,7.01]
CUT(aaa, 3)
# $output
# [1] (0.994,3] (0.994,3] (3,5]     (3,5]     (3,5]     (0.994,3] (3,5]     (3,5]    
# [9] (3,5]     (5,7.01]  (5,7.01] 
# Levels: (0.994,3] (3,5] (5,7.01]
# 
# $ranges
#   lower upper
# 1 0.994     3
# 2     3     5
# 3     5  7.01
```

And, `right = FALSE`:

```
cut(aaa, 3, dig.lab = 4, ordered = TRUE, right = FALSE)
#  [1] [0.994,2.998) [0.994,2.998) [2.998,5.002) [2.998,5.002) [2.998,5.002)
#  [6] [0.994,2.998) [2.998,5.002) [2.998,5.002) [2.998,5.002) [5.002,7.006)
# [11] [5.002,7.006)
# Levels: [0.994,2.998) < [2.998,5.002) < [5.002,7.006)
CUT(aaa, 3, dig.lab = 4, ordered = TRUE, right = FALSE)
# $output
#  [1] [0.994,2.998) [0.994,2.998) [2.998,5.002) [2.998,5.002) [2.998,5.002)
#  [6] [0.994,2.998) [2.998,5.002) [2.998,5.002) [2.998,5.002) [5.002,7.006)
# [11] [5.002,7.006)
# Levels: [0.994,2.998) < [2.998,5.002) < [5.002,7.006)

# $ranges
#   lower upper
# 1 0.994 2.998
# 2 2.998 5.002
# 3 5.002 7.006
```

Comment: Sorry for the very late comment, but now I'm checking `example(cut.default)` and the second alternative it's more comfortable for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most answers to this question that I found work on reversing the constructed string or writing your own alternative version of cut.

However, R has the function `trace()` which gives you the opportunity out of the box to inject code into a function. You can use this to "hack" a function for side effects, such as extracting a non-returned internal object.

```
> trace(cut.default,quote(these_breaks<<-breaks),at=7)
Tracing function "cut.default" in package "base"
[1] "cut.default"


> invisible(cut(5:100,7))
Tracing cut.default(5:100, 7) step 7 
> these_breaks
[1]   4.90500  18.57143  32.14286  45.71429  59.28571  72.85714  86.42857 100.09500

> invisible(cut(2:10,2))
Tracing cut.default(2:10, 2) step 7 
> these_breaks
[1]  1.992  6.000 10.008
```

I use `at=7` because I checked beforehand at which point in the function body the breaks variable is alread calculated and not changed anymore. You can find this point via `as.list(body(cut.default))`. The `7` might need to be changed for future R versions.

I use the quoted expression `these_breaks<<-breaks` to copy the internal `breaks` to an object in the global env. In package code, one could do this more elegantly with a predefined env.

```
breaks_env <- new.env()
untrace(cut.default)
trace(cut.default,quote(assign("these_breaks",breaks,envir = breaks_env)),at=7)

invisible(cut(5:100,7))
breaks_env[['these_breaks']]
rm(these_breaks,envir=breaks_env)

invisible(cut(2:10,2))
breaks_env[['these_breaks']]
```