# Bin new data according to existing intervals given as factor levels

Tags: regex, r

I have a factor with levels which represent intervals (as produced by `cut`):

```
> head(data.train$glucose)
[1] [0,126]   [0,126]   (126,199] [0,126]   [0,126]   [0,126]  
Levels: [0,126] (126,199]
```

Now I want to generate a new factor with the same levels from a numeric vector so that when the respective number falls into the first interval (e.g. 24) it becomes `[0,126]` and if it falls into the second interval (e.g. 153) it becomes `(126,199]`.

The number of intervals can differ as can the form of the brackets (depending on whether they are open or closed intervals).

I think I can use `sub` together with `cut` for that (as in the last example in the helpfile of `cut`) but I am not very good at it to make it general enough. Is there also another way which is a little bit more intuitive? But perhaps I am thinking too complicated anyway...

If you give a solution with `sub` please explain the expression. Please also do not give solutions with functions from other packages as I am developing a package myself and I want to keep it as lean as possible.

Comment: @JasonAizkalns: This seems more complicated than previously thought - please see my comment on your answer.

Comment: How about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19689542)

Comment: How did you end up solving this problem? Is there a more easy way than what I suggested?

Comment: @DavidH: Basically I used a variant of your method and changed the interval generating function so that only "standard" intervals are being generated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for an elegant way to do this, but ended up using regex like you suggested:

```
ints<-cut(1:10,5)
set.seed(345)
a<-runif(20,1,10)

    # get levels
levs <- levels(ints)
# remove brackets
levs.num <- sub(  "^[\\(\\[]{1}(.+)[\\)\\]]{1}$" , "\\1" ,levs , perl = TRUE)
levs.right <- sub(  "^[\\(\\[]{1}.+([\\)\\]]{1})$" , "\\1" ,levs , perl = TRUE)
levs.left <- sub(  "^([\\(\\[]{1}).+[\\)\\]]{1}$" , "\\1" ,levs , perl = TRUE)
# get breaks
breaks <- unique(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(levs.num ,","))))

if(all(levs.right=="]")){ 
    right.arg <- TRUE
}else if(all(levs.left=="[")){
  right.arg <- FALSE
}else{
      stop("problem")
  }
table(cut(a,breaks , right = right.arg ))
```

My regex should select everything between [ or ( and ] or ) and return it

Comment: Thank you. I think the problem with this solution is that you lose the information on whether the intervals are open or closed - so the resulting levels will differ which is a problem in case because there will be some matching operation afterwards. Do you see a fix for this in your code?

Comment: I made some changes to account for the cases where all bins are right closed or left closed. Mixed cases will be more difficult to account for.